# JSON Schema validate properties are required based on enum values

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "FileType": { "type": "string" },
        "Version": { "type": "string" },
        "Expt": 
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": 
              {
                "design": { "type": "string","enum": ["TS", "DR", "BC", "DP"] }
              },
            "required": ["design"],
            "additionalProperties": false
         },
       "Rout": 
         {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": 
            {
             "timeUnits": {"type": "string", "enum": ["sec", "min", "hr"] },
             "setTime": { "type": "number", "minimum": 0.0, "maximum": 50 }
           },
           "required": ["timeUnits"],
           "additionalProperties": false
        }
     }
 }
```

1. if `design` == `DR` or `BC` then `Rout`->`setTime` should exist
2. if `design` == `TS` or `DP`, `setTime` should not exist

#### Invalid instances

`setTime` is not allowed

```json
    {
    "Expt": { "design": "TS" },
    "Rout": { "timeUnits": "sec", "setTime":12 }
    }
```

`setTime` should be `required`

```json
    {
    "Expt": { "design": "BC"},
    "Rout": { "timeUnits": "sec" }
    }
```

---

#### Valid instances

```json
    {
    "Expt": { "design": "TS" },
    "Rout": { "timeUnits": "sec" }
    }
```

```json
    {
    
    "Expt": { "design": "BC" },
    "Rout": { "timeUnits": "sec", "setTime":12 }
    
    }
```

I have tried multiple combinations of if-then-else, oneof, allof in the schema but I'm unable to validate `setTime` for `BC` or `DR`. I expect an error for `setTime` with the values `TS` or `DP`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a number of ways which you indicated, here we have an example of `oneOf`

Each subschema is almost duplicated yet we use the `enum` to create a difference between the schemas.
`Rout` has been moved to `$defs` for reuse and then `setTime` is defined and `required`, `unevaluatedProperties` prevents any other properties in the `Rout` schema for the first `oneOf` schema.

`unevaluatedProperties` restricts the use of `setTime` in the second schema.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "Expt",
                "Rout"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "FileType": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Version": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Expt": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "design": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "DR",
                                "BC"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "design"
                    ],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                },
                "Rout": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/Rout",
                    "required": [
                        "setTime"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "setTime": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0,
                            "maximum": 50
                        }
                    },
                    "unevaluatedProperties": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "Expt",
                "Rout"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "FileType": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Version": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Expt": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "design": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "TS",
                                "DP"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "design"
                    ],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                },
                "Rout": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/Rout",
                    "unevaluatedProperties": false
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "$defs": {
        "Rout": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "timeUnits": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "sec",
                        "min",
                        "hr"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "timeUnits"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I am not getting the desired validation, from the above schema

Comment: Sorry my mistake its validating for TS without setTime and BC with setTime, but TS with setTime or BC without setTime (Ideally say setTime unexcepted in case of TS and excepted in case of BC) instead its says TS is not one of ["BC","DP"] which is indirect way of saying. Is a clever way to warn

Comment: Your comment is not clear.  Does it work for you or you have some other requirements from the original request?  You can play with the enum values to get the desired behavior

Comment: It validates the file against schema only when condition are met E.g `"Expt": { "design": "TS" },Rout": { timeUnits": "sec" }`  or `"Expt": { "design": "BC"},"Rout": { "timeUnits": "sec","setTime" : 1}`  Valid But if pass `"Expt": { "design": "BC" },Rout": { timeUnits": "sec" } ` or`"Expt": { "design": "TS"},"Rout": { "timeUnits": "sec","setTime" : 1}`, I was excepting validator flags saying design=BC required setTime or when  desgin = TS, setTime was unexpected.

Comment: a valid schema can only be when the conditions are met.  If you pass an invalid schema, you will get the error output similar to your expectation.  if you want to see the full output, you can use a tool like https://www.json-everything.net/json-schema. That will give you the full details of the results, either true or false

Comment: Is there a better way of checking this condition, I tried if-then-else conditional check it is not checking the condition from 'if',  always excepting what is there in 'then' condition, The schema is quite big so I can't extend Rout based on design condition from experiment as mentioned by @jeremy

Comment: `"Expt": { "design": "DR" }, "Rout": { "tUnits": "s", "qUnits": "uM" }` in this case since setTime is missing schema should check in if-then-else condition warn and for `"Expt": { "design": "TS"}, "Rout": { "tUnits": "s", "qUnits": "uM" } ` it should validate but for the same TS if I pass setTime in Rout section then warn unexpected setTime logically if design == "DR", then Rout's setTime should exist

Comment: `"Expt": { "type": "object","properties": {"design": { "type": "string", "enum": ["TS", "DR", "BC", "DP"] }
      }, "Rout": { "type": "object", "properties": { "tUnits": { "type": "string", "enum": ["s", "m"] },"qUnits": { "type": "string", "enum": ["nM", "uM"] }, "setTime": { "type": "number"} },  "if": {
        "properties": {
          "Expt": { "properties": { "design": { "const": "DR" }  } }  } },
      "then": { "required": ["setTime"] },
      "else": { 
        "not": { "required": ["setTime"]  } },` This is the schema but its always excepting setTime

Comment: the flags are you a expecting to suggest where you made a mistake is dependent on the implementation you are using. Some validators will have custom messaging.  Can you share what is not working for you? It seems to work based on your requirements, but you are asking for human readable error messaging to suggest something else to the user. That's not found in every implementation

Answer (score 0):

Here's another flavor with `if, then, else`

You had the `if, then, else` at the wrong level to validate your conditionals.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Expt": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "design": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "TS",
                        "DR",
                        "BC",
                        "DP"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "Rout": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "tUnits": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "s",
                        "m"
                    ]
                },
                "qUnits": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "nM",
                        "uM"
                    ]
                },
                "setTime": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "if": {
        "required": [
            "Expt"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "Expt": {
                "required": [
                    "design"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "design": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": ["DR", "BC"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "Rout": {
                "required": [
                    "setTime"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "else": {
        "properties": {
            "Rout": {
                "not": {
                    "required": [
                        "setTime"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```